Django Admin Site Not Enforcing Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) with django-otp and django-two-factor-auth
Problem Description:
I am trying to enforce two-factor authentication (2FA) for the Django admin site using the django-otp and django-two-factor-auth packages. Despite following the setup steps, the admin login does not require 2FA and allows users to log in with just their username and password.
My Setup

Django Version: 4.2.11
django-otp Version: 1.5.2
django-two-factor-auth Version: 1.17.0
Python Version: 3.10

What i've done

Installed Required Packages: pip install django-otp django-two-factor-auth
Updated INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py: INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.admin', 'django_otp', 'django_otp.plugins.otp_email', 'two_factor', 'two_factor.plugins.email', ... ]
Configured Middleware in settings.py: MIDDLEWARE = [ 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware', 'two_factor.middleware.threadlocals.ThreadLocals', ... ]
Patched the Admin Site in urls.py: from django.contrib import admin from two_factor.admin import AdminSiteOTPRequired admin.site.__class__ = AdminSiteOTPRequired urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('account/', include(('two_factor.urls', 'two_factor'), namespace='two_factor')), ... ]
2FA Settings in settings.py: TWO_FACTOR_PATCH_ADMIN = True TWO_FACTOR_LOGIN_URL = 'two_factor:login' LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/' LOGIN_URL = 'two_factor:login'
Added 2FA Devices: I added an email device using the two_factor_add management command.

The issue
Even after following these steps, the admin login page does not prompt for 2FA. It allows me to log in directly with just the username and password, bypassing the 2FA requirement entirely.
Errors in logs
Here are some relevant log entries when attempting to log in: [22/Aug/2024 16:24:34] INFO "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 [22/Aug/2024 16:24:35] INFO Response for URL: /account/account/login/, Status Code: 200, User: Anonymous, IP: 127.0.0.1
What I've Tried:

Ensuring django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware is correctly placed in the middleware list.
Restarting the Django server after each configuration change.

What could be causing the Django admin to bypass the 2FA requirement? Is there something I'm missing in my setup? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
